# Import SVG - green icon

Tags: svg

I've imported an SVG - all looks as expected but I can't make a mesh out of it - the icons look different - I can't reproduce this - can anyone work out what I've done?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You imported it as a Grease Pencil object using *File > Import > SVG as Grease Pencil*.

Use *File > Import > Scalable Vector graphics (.svg)* instead, make sure the addon is active in the user preferences.

Comment: That's great - thanks - @Duarte - is there a way to convert grease pencil into objs or alembics to pass on to Maya?

Comment: Of course - I have no reputation yet and can't upvote - though I did try.  It hasn't completely solved my issue.  I am a flame artist with a fair bit of experience and just dipping my toes into cg.  I don't understand how to convert grease pencil into something other Maya artists can use.  They asked for a Mesh but that is not possible to convert from grease pencil according to the interactive menus.

Comment: It is probably easier to just re-import the object as regular bezier curve and export that.

Comment: Hi @duarte you migh be right - what I really liked about the grease pencil import was that it imported the SVG groups as separate layers/grease pencil geos.  This was really useful for me.  When I imported the SVG as curves I got 140 curves which is a bit more unmanageable.  This is why I was trying to use the grease pencil option because the import respected the grouping hierarchy I had created in the vector drawing.  Is there a way I can import the groups?  Or would I have to export them separately then collect them in blender?

Comment: There isn't as far as I know, you can manually rearrange them into collections after importing. If there is too much stuff you can import in several steps by layers to make it easier